# Transforming an operation involving the components of matrixes, ${C}_{i j}=B_{i k} B_{j l} A_{k l}$, into a matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, matrix-equations

The components of a matrix ${\mathbf{C}}=({C}_{i j})_{n\times n}$ are obtained from the components of two matrices ${\mathbf{A}}=({A}_{i j})_{n\times n}$ and ${\mathbf{B}}=({B}_{i j})_{n\times n}$ in the following way:

$${C}_{i j}=B_{i k} B_{j l} A_{k l} \tag{1}$$

Using Einstein's notation. I need to express $(1)$ as matrix multiplication.

**My attempt**

I know that for square matrices $n \times n$, if $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}·\mathbf{b}$, then their components will satisfy that
$$c_{i j}= a_{i k} b_{k j}$$

So, in $(1)$, $B_{i k} A_{k l}=X_{il}$ will correspond to the matrix multiplication $\mathbf{B}·\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{X}$, getting that

$${C}_{i j}= B_{j l} X_{il}$$

However, since the second index in $B_{j l}$ and the first index in $X_{il}$ doesn't match, how could this be expressed in terms of a matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dovetail indices. Since $C_{\color{red}{i}\color{limegreen}{j}}=B_{\color{red}{i}\color{blue}{k}}A_{\color{blue}{k}\color{brown}{l}}B^T_{\color{brown}{l}\color{limegreen}{j}}$, $C=BAB^T$.